# Unicode char issues

Tags: unicode, char, turkish

When I assign word that included Turkish unicode char to a string variable,
Turkish chars transforming other unicode chars.

Here the debugger's pic:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wXl0.png)

Comment: There's probably a discrepancy between the character set used by the IDE and the one displayed in the debugger. I presume this is a Windows wide character build?

Comment: Hi Mark probably Yes. This problem appears only vs 2015 before I used vs 2013 there is no problem

Comment: If you do a "Save As" there's probably a setting for the encoding. Set the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Hi Mark, It worked like a charm. Please answer question. I'll accept as correct. Thank you and your time

Comment: My comment was far too vague to make a good answer. I'm just glad I was able to help!

Comment: Can you try Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors

Select a font which can support Unicode like Courier New?

I can't get Chinese Characters to shows at all. It works perfectly prior to VS2015.

Comment: Hi I'm using Droid Sans Mono.There was problem at only one code file.The file that added by EF 6 Migration. But now perfect